# MySQL joining tables Q

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables one called Doctor, Person and one called Appointment. They have doctor_id in common relationship but only person holds their Last_Name.

I need to be able Produce a list of doctor IDs together with the number of appointments made for each doctor with zero or more appointment and also the doctors name.

How would I implement the the name of the doctor?

Here are the tables:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT doctor.doctor_id, COUNT(appt_time) AS No_APP 
FROM doctor LEFT JOIN appointment ON doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id 
GROUP BY doctor.doctor_id;
```

Comment: can you post the people table as well please

Comment: You would need the person_id in table doctor, and than join does tables by that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more left join for the new table :

```
SELECT doctor.doctor_id, COUNT(appt_time) AS No_APP, person.Last_name
FROM doctor LEFT JOIN appointment ON doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id 
             LEFT JOIN person on person.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id 
GROUP BY doctor.doctor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the person table contains a link to doctors (will update when yo post third table if needed)

```
SELECT d.doctor_id, p.last_name, COUNT(a.appt_time) AS No_APP 
FROM doctor d
LEFT JOIN appointment a ON d.doctor_id = a.doctor_id
LEFT JOIN person p ON d.doctor_id = p.doctor_id
GROUP BY d.doctor_id;
```